Writing the equation of a family of circles touching two circles
I know that the equation of a circle passing through the intersection of two circles is $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ and I know that the equation of a circle passing through the intersection points of a line and a circle is $S+ \lambda L=0$.
However, I was thinking, how do I write a similar form for the equation of a circle touching two non-intersecting circles (they can be internally or externally tangent to each other)?
I looked at Family of Circles Touching a Circle and a Line but that didn't answer my question, and when I tried to do this analytically by assuming a radius $r$ and center $(\alpha, \beta)$ of the variable circle, and fixed circles $S_1, S_2$ I got the following relations;
$$r+\sqrt{g_1^2+f_1^2-c_1}=\sqrt{(\alpha +g_1)^2+(\beta+f_1)^2}$$
$$r+\sqrt{g_2^2+f_2^2-c_2}=\sqrt{(\alpha +g_2)^2+(\beta+f_2)^2}$$
I also remembered that the center(s) of such a family of circles will lie on the radical axis i.e. on $S_1=S_2$.
However, I'm unable to produce a simple form like $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ or so from these relations. Can anyone help me do so or direct me to the appropriate answer?
